change modifiers values ​with a gizmo
I see a lot of potential in gizmos, yet there is very little info on it. For example, I want to modify the properties of the modifiers or geometry nodes of my object with a gizmo.
How to do this ?
What exactly do you mean by a "gizmo"?
When I think of gizmo, I first refer to gizmos objects.

But also to the gizmo in the python template like these.
in gizmo_simple.py :

in gizmo_custom_geometry.py :

But for me a gizmo is an interactive visual element which is not found in the outliner and only appears when an object is selected and which modifies some of the properties of this object when it is moved.
And I actually want to modify certain properties of geometry nodes using a gizmo.

What exactly do you mean by a "gizmo"? Please add more details so that we can help.

Geometry Nodes gizmos are planned by the devs. https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes-gizmos-feedback/32073 I don't think it will make its way into 4.2 but maybe 4.3 ?

In the meantime you can always put your geometry nodes in a Group and add inputs to the properties you want to change. They will then be easily available on the Modifiers panel of the Geometry Modifier.
